# How to upload base64 pdf to S3 with dotnet SDK using PutObjectAsync

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, amazon-s3, sdk

I'm trying to upload a base64 pdf to S3 using dotnet SDK. The file is being uploaded but it is being shown as a blank pdf. Am I missing something?

I think the problem may be something to do with the way I'm uploading it? I've tried just using illustrationDocumentBody and sending it up as Bytes. illustrationDocumentBody by itself uploads the file but gives me unable to load pdf when I try and view it in S3.

```
try
{
      await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(new PutObjectRequest
      {
                ContentBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(illustrationDocumentBody)),
                ContentType = "application/pdf",
                BucketName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ESIS_SYNC_BUCKET"),
                Key = $"Opportunities/{oppName}/ESIS-{brokerName}-{productCode}-{customerName}.pdf",
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl
      });
}
catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
{
      Console.WriteLine(
                    "Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
      Console.WriteLine(
                "Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
}
```

I'm expecting to be able to view the PDF but instead it's uploading a blank PDF. The base64 string is also being used by Sendgrid to be sent as an email and that is working so I don't think its to do with the base64 string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDFs are binary files - they're not plain text.

You're taking your base64-encoded binary file, and turning that back into a byte array using `Convert.FromBase64String(illustrationDocumentBody)` (which is fine), but you're then interpreting that binary PDF data as a UTF-8 string (with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(...)`).

But, PDF data is not a string, and can't be interpreted as a string.

You probably want to use `PutObjectRequest.InputStream` (which lets you use any binary data, as a `Stream`), rather than `PutObjectRequest.ContentBody` (which only supports a string).

The easiest way to get a `Stream` from a byte array is to use a `MemoryStream`.

```
using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(illustrationDocumentBody)))
{
    await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(new PutObjectRequest
    {
        InputStream = inputStream,
        ContentType = "application/pdf",
        BucketName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ESIS_SYNC_BUCKET"),
        Key = $"Opportunities/{oppName}/ESIS-{brokerName}-{productCode}-{customerName}.pdf",
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl
    });
}
```